# how to update quantiy by runnnig multiple queries?

Tags: php

how do i run these two query at once where in tbl_purchase_return it inserts new data and on the otherhand updates quantiy from tbl_product?

```
$query= "insert into tbl_purchase_return(product_id,supplier_id,quantity,date) values ($prd_id,$sup_id,$quantity,'$date')";

$query="UPDATE  quantity  AND set quantity=  getQuantityFomProductId($id)- $quantity  WHERE `tbl_product`.`id` = $id";
```

Comment: Write it as single string with `;` separating them.

Answer (score 0):

You first get the quantity of the product then fire your first query and on success ( after getting last inserted id) of that you run your second query.